# Set of all roots of unity

Tags: complex-numbers

We know that in the set of nth roots of unity there are exactly $n$ distinct complex numbers: $C_n = \{z \in \mathbb{C} : z^{n} = 1 \}   = \{e^{i2k\pi/n}, \;  k = 0, 1, ...,n-1 \} $ and they lie on the unit circle. Now collect all roots of unity for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and consider the set $C =  \{C_n, \;  n \in \mathbb{N}\}$.

Is the set $C$ the unit circle, that is $\{C_n, \;  n \in \mathbb{N}\} = \{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| = 1 \}$ ?

Obviously $\{C_n, \;  n \in \mathbb{N}\} \subseteq \{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| = 1 \}$, but I didn't manage to prove the other inclusion (if it is true).

Comment: No. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/184666/help-proving-the-primitive-roots-of-unity-are-dense-in-the-unit-circle

Comment: Well, no: of course not. There are many element in $\;S^1=$  the unit circle, that are *not* roots of unity, for example $\;e^{i/\pi^2}\;$ ...